# how to set different color for each cluster

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(Name = c("ScoreBIO", "ScoreBIO", "ScoreBIO"), 
    group = c("Class1", "Class2", "Class3"), median = c(18.46044132, 
    10.75826578, 0), SD = c(0.531335266, 15.21448537, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I plot it like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = median))+
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = median - SD, ymax = median + SD), width = 0.2, colour = "gray25")
```

but it gives me all the same color as gray25

I tried to add this

scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey80", "grey30","grey50"))

or different color but still cannot get this to be different color with the legend position

```
theme(legend.position = "cornertop")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
To get the same color in the `geom_errorbar` put the color aesthetics inside of `aes`:

```
library(ggplot)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = median, color=group))+
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes( color = df$group, ymin = median - SD, ymax = median + SD), width = 0.2)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey80", "grey30","grey50"))
```

[image]

**First answer:**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = median, color=group))+
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = median - SD, ymax = median + SD), width = 0.2, colour = "gray25")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey80", "grey30","grey50"))
```

[image]

Comment: how can I have all the bar stuff also the same color for each class ?

Comment: Please see my update!